# selenium.click is not working while running the script when selecting an item from a list generated by Ajax search

Tags: selenium-ide

The functionality is such that some search criteria is entered in a search box, an ajax search is performed and a list of items matching the search criteria is shown. An item is selected from this list and gets loaded into the search input box. When i am recording using Selenium IDE, the selecting of item from the list, the command is click. But when i am running the script with the click command, it seems it is not selecting the item from the list and loading it into the box. Some one please suggest what command should i use. I have tried with clickat() but it doesnt work. 
I am using Selenium IDE 1.5.0 to record and writing scripts in Eclipse Junit platform.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get an answer? you should accept answer if it worked or ansswer your own question if you got other workaround or solution or leave a comment. then you have more chances of future questions being answered. see [FAQ]

Comment: @tgkprog Thank you. I will keep this point in mind from now on and have also added my answer. :)

Comment: okay great. You should accept your own answer so this question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the above scenario. I am using `Actions` class. Using that I am focusing on the search item that fulfills my criteria and performing click action (instead of using `click()` and `clickat()` methods)

`Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  builder.moveToElement(item).build().perform();`
//item is the search item i want to select  `item.click();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's a timing issue. The click in the list happens before it is present in browser. You should add before the click command an explicit wait like "waitForElementPresent".